# Proving a set is countable

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, proof-writing

Let X be an enumerable set and let Y be any set. If there is a surjective function f : X → Y, how do I prove that Y is countable?

I know a set is enumerable if there's a bijection $Z^+$ → X, so that it
is equipotent to $Z^+$. I also know that a set is countable if it is finite or denumerable, I'm just not sure how to tie that all together?

Comment: Hint: What is a surjective function?

Comment: its when at least one point can be mapped to the same spot i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We  generate subset $X'$ by enumerating $X$, and mapping $f$ on each element $x$. If we have already seen $f(x)$ previously in the enumeration, we discard $x$.

Since we discarded only duplicate results, we have a subset $X' \subseteq X$ such that $X'$ is still surjective.

However no two elements of $X'$ map to the same element in $Y$, so it's also injective. Therefore $f$ is a  bijective mapping from $X'$ to $Y$.

Since $X$ is countable, $X' \subseteq X$ is as well, therefore $Y$ must be as well.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you. How do we know X is countable though? because it's enumerable?

Comment: @user3427042 A set is countable if and only if it's enumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi:\Bbb Z^+\to X$ be a bijection. Define a map $\psi:Y\to X$ as follows: for each $y\in Y$, choose one $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$, and let this $x=\psi(y)$. Note that $\psi$ need not be unique, but its existence suffices. Now $\phi^{-1}\circ\psi:Y\to\Bbb Z^+$ is an injection (show it). So $Y$ is at most countable i.e. countably infinite or just finite.